# How to compare the amount of numbers of something in a list and have it return true or false?

Tags: python

I want to compare the amount of even and odd numbers in a list and if there are more odd numbers than even ones, I want it to return true. Otherwise, false.

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far, and the (incorrect) answer it gives. What is the URL of this homework assignment?

Comment: Have you learned how to iterate through a list? Have you learned how to check if a number is even or odd? Have you learned how to increment a variable? If yes, what's the problem? If no... well... why not?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function that’s getting a list
2. Create 2 counters (odd and even)
3. Run a loop on the list
4. If the element is odd add one to odd counter
5. Otherwise add one the even counter
6. After the loop finishes check if the odd counter is bigger, if so return true
7. Otherwise return false

Comment: You only need one counter that you increment *or* decrement depending on the parity of an input number. Once you've seen the entire input, the counter will be positive or negative, depending on which type of number was more common.

Comment: You right man, but I'm thinking your solution far more complicated for the guy